# jQuery Auto Scroll to DIV - But Auto Scroll Works only on First Page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scrolltop

I'm creating Quiz site and have a confusing problem. Because explanation will show only after one answer is selected - that is "hidden" element I wrapped that element into visible DIV.

Code I'm using simply, after user clicks on answer auto-scroll to visible DIV within explanation wrapped inside.

My auto-scroll code is:

```
var elem = $('.scroll');
            if(elem) {
            $(window).scrollTop(elem.offset().top).scrollLeft(elem.offset().left);
        }
```

**ISSUE:** After user click on **Continue** button, on the next question, after answer is selected - **nothing happens**. Note - there's no page refresh after continue button, whole quiz is within same container, as a slider.

**Live Quiz Example:** [Link for Quiz](https://devtriviaoadev.wpengine.com/test-your-memory-and-see-what-you-remember-from-high-school-history-by-taking-this-quiz/)

Comment: And of course, someone gave -1 because there's no more explanation :) Well, this is complete WordPress plugin, there's no sense to place whole code here. I'm just asking if someone had similar issue with auto-scrolling function within same container, and if YES, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know where you will bind your code, but in the example site,
each **continue** button have to bind your code with their own one `'.scroll'` element.

if just `$('.scroll')`,
jquery selector will find all of `.scroll` class element (found 40 in the example site) and `offset()` function will be executed with first of all `.scroll` elements (not a valid index of them)

so, for example,

the **continue** button in the second quiz(Benjamin Franklin) should bind with second `$('.scroll').eq(1)` element. not a `$('.scroll')`.

```js
var elem = $('.scroll').eq(0);
if(elem) {
 $(window).scrollTop(elem.offset().top).scrollLeft(elem.offset().left);
}
```

i can't see whole source in that page. but maybe you can bind the event once and just assign index to `eq()`.

---

### added

i tracked event and found your code in the 'quiz-trivia.js'.

**changed one thing.**

(roughly write down that i tracked and answer)

1. click answer .
2. on click event of `'.wpvqgr-answer'`, `wpvqgr.selectAnswer()` function will be executed.
3. then in `selectAnswer()`, need to find `'.scroll'` element in same area(ex: in first page **Albert Einstein**,  first element of 40 `'.scroll'`. so

```js
// The function is given a parameter called question_id which indicating the question index. 
// we can find the same area .scroll with this index

// not $('.scroll').
var elem = $('.scroll').eq(question_id);
```

4. `'.scroll'` of same area will be found. and behind, your code will work correctly

Comment: TBH I don't understand quite well your comment and also - I will place any part of code here, but I don't know what do you need to analyze deeper into @user7725963

Comment: @Eager2Learn i saw your comment late. i edited comment